# Как правильно вызвать несколько функций в одной инструкции?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.Прикрепил небольшой пример.Интересует именно то, как правильно написать последовательный вызов функций ( как при нажатии на clearBtn в примере)

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var sumBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-sum');
var maxBtn =document.querySelector('.btn-max');
var clearBtn =document.querySelector('.clear');
var itemSum =document.querySelector('.item-sum');
var itemMax =document.querySelector('.item-max');
var fillBtn = document.querySelector('.fill');
sumBtn.addEventListener('click',showSum);
maxBtn.addEventListener('click',showMax);
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  clear();
  showSum();
  showMax();
});
fillBtn.addEventListener('click', fill);
function showSum() {
 var result = arr.reduce(function(sum, current) {
   return sum + current;
  });
  itemSum.innerHTML = result;
}
function showMax() {
 var result = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  itemMax.innerHTML = result;
}
function clear() {
 arr = [0];
}
function fill() {
 arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="item-sum"></div>
  <button class="btn-sum">Sum</button>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="item-max"></div>
  <button class="btn-max">Max</button>
</div>
<button class="clear">Clear</button>
<button class="fill">Fill</button>
```

Comment: Что Вас, собственно, не устраивает?

Comment: @Igor интересуюсь, нормально ли так делать?

Comment: Да, так делать нормально и правильно.

Comment: @Igor спасибо за ответ, не знаю почему, но меня немного смущала такая запись.

Comment: @pi4yyy, а как можно сделать по другому?

Comment: @Grundy это человек как раз и надеялся узнать :)

Answer (score 4):

Можно придумать много способов, только есть ли в этом смысл? ))

```
const run = (...funcs) => funcs.forEach(func => func());

run(clear, showSum, showMax);
```